# How to change "Publish" button text for specific page

Tags: uploads, media

I am trying to make one specific page on my wordpress installation to have a different text on the "Upload" button.

So i tried:

```
function change_settingspage_publish_button( $translation, $text ) {

    if ( '567' == get_the_ID() && $text == 'Publish' ) {

        return 'Save Settings';

    } else {

        return $translation;
    }
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_settingspage_publish_button', 10, 2 );
```

(Where '567' is the page id). but it doesn't work. any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to change the Publish button's text in the Block Editor and came across this question. With the answers given it wasn't changing the text. With the Gutenberg update, I realized it would have to be done with JavaScript. I found this response: [Changing text within the Block Editor](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/328121/changing-text-within-the-block-editor)

Which I applied in my plugin code (you can insert this into your Themes functions.php file, too).

```
function change_publish_button_text() {
// Make sure the `wp-i18n` has been "done".
  if ( wp_script_is( 'wp-i18n' ) ) :
  ?>
    <script>
      wp.i18n.setLocaleData({'Publish': ['Custom Publish Text']});
    </script>

    <script>
      wp.i18n.setLocaleData({'Publish…': ['Custom Publish Text']});
    </script>
  <?php
  endif;
}

add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', 'change_publish_button_text', 11 );
```

Which to your specific request to target only on a post ID you can do this:

```
function change_publish_button_text() {
  global $post;
  if (get_the_ID() == '123') {
    // Make sure the `wp-i18n` has been "done".
    if ( wp_script_is( 'wp-i18n' ) ) :
      ?>
        <script>
          wp.i18n.setLocaleData({'Publish': ['Custom Publish Text']});
        </script>

        <script>
          wp.i18n.setLocaleData({'Publish…': ['Custom Publish Text']});
        </script>
      <?php
      endif;
    }
  }

add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', 'change_publish_button_text', 11 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tried this code below, it works for me.

```
function change_publish_button( $translation, $text ) {
if ( 'CUSTOM_POST_TYPE' == get_post_type() && ($text == 'Publish' || $text == 'Update') ) {
    return 'Save';
 } else {
    return $translation;
 }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't change it for a page id as i asked, but for specific post type. read the question again.

Comment: @mondi if you look into the code you can easily change it for a page id where you see ''CUSTOM_POST_TYPE'' == get_post_type()  declare like this  if($page = get_page_by_path( 'about' )

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this if you'd like to target a specific post/page ID.

```
add_action('admin_notices', 'check_id_before_text_change_wpse_273920');

function check_id_before_text_change_wpse_273920() {
    global $post;
    //if post isn't set bail
    if(null == $post)
        return;

    $id = $post->ID;
    //add our filter if the id matches
    if($id == '567') {
        add_filter('gettext', 'change_publish_text_wpse_273920', 30, 2);
    }
}

function change_publish_text_wpse_273920($translation, $text) {
    //if this runs and publish isn't in the text
    //we still want to return something
    $rtn_text = $translation;

    if($text === 'Publish') {
        $rtn_text = 'Save setting';
    }

 return $rtn_text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to change nothing.

Comment: What is the ID of the page you are on? Also what is the current status? I've tested this on a site of my own so I know it works

Comment: the ID is 784 (of course i changed it in the code) and the status is publish. weird. why can it be?

Comment: Where are you adding the code?

Comment: Also try `var_dump($post); die();` before the `if(null == $post)` to see if that produces a post object, if it does try `var_dump($post->ID)` to confirm you are using the correct ID in the if statement.

Comment: I put that in the end of functions.php and it does produces a post object. and it does returns the correct (matching) post id.